# Postgres multiplication function added to field with database trigger

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, insert-update, database-trigger

I have 2 tables (within the same POSTGRESQL database) called respectively **Orders** and **Products**. They look like this more or less:

**Products**:

-*integer* id (primary)

-*text* description

-*numeric* unitprice

**Orders**:

-*integer* id (primary)

-*integer* productid (foreign key to product.id)

-*integer* quantity (amount ordered)

-*numeric* totalprice (Orders.number * Products.unitprice)

What I need is a procedure that upon database trigger will update the fields that are missing the totalprice field.

So far my procedure looks something like this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE update_totalprice()
    BEGIN
         UPDATE Orders 
         SET Orders.totalprice=Orders.quantity*Products.unitprice 
         FROM Orders, Products
         WHERE Orders.productid = Products.id AND Orders.totalprice = NULL 
    END;
```

I then tried creating a Database trigger to recall the procedure when the table changes.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER check_Orders
        BEFORE UPDATE ON Orders
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_totalprice();
```

And this is where I kind of get stuck, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

---

**Edit**:

**Found** the **solution**, in the end they were all **syntax errors**.

The function itself looks something like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION orders_totalprice() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $orders_totalprice$
            BEGIN
                UPDATE orders SET totalprice = NEW.numberofproducts * products.unitprice FROM products
                WHERE NEW.productid = products.id;
                IF NOT FOUND THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $orders_totalprice$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

While the trigger query something like this:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_orderstotalprice
    AFTER INSERT ON orders
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE orders_totalprice();
```

Comment: try `..FROM Products..` instead of `..FROM Orders, Products ..`

Comment: 2 other issues... firstly don't use capital letters for table/field/etc names unless you're double quoting them, as they will be treated as lowercase otherwise. Secondly you shouldn't even have a "totalprice" column, given that you already have a quantity and unit price... just calculate the total on the fly, otherwise you have to update totalprice every time the quantity or unit price changes!

Comment: Capital letters are used only in the reported example, however it is my bad indeed, sorry for the bad formatting. Will keep it in mind next time. I'm well aware of the fact that normally one shouldn't really add a totalprice like that, it's a silly idea, however I want to see how I can make it work, regardless of how unclean it is, just to know that it can be done. 
Unfortunately changing from "From Orders, Products" to "From Products" did not solve the issue.
Thank you both

Comment: @Ledio Has RIKI's suggestion helped/worked?